# Java character encoding issue, currencies not displaying correctly in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, character-encoding

I am having a problem where my JSPs are not correctly displaying many currencies like the euro symbol, i am using JDBC to retrieve the information from MySQL and am currently using tomcat v7.0.37.

At first i thought it could be a tomcat issue so i added 'URIEncoding="UTF-8' to my server.xml and in various place in the server.xml but had no luck, any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks.

Comment: Can [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebI18N5.html) be helpful ?

Comment: What does it display? A question mark? Or some garbage? And how about other Unicode characters on the page?

Comment: Is the information saved correctly in the DB to begin with ? Post that is it retrieved correctly from the DB ? You can then check if the retrieved info is displayed on the JSP with the right encoding.

Comment: @Thilo it display this ¬ on the page instead of the euro symbol.

Comment: @DeepakBala it's saved in the database fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what the problem was, the data i was getting from the database was a clob data type, the way i was converting the clob to a string was causing the encoding issue below is how my code was first.

```
Clob clob=resultSet.getClob(1);

Reader reader = clob.getCharacterStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int c;
  while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
 }
 reader.close();
 out.close();
 return out.toString();
```

I changed the way i converted the clob to a string by performing a sub string on the clob and it fixed it.

```
Clob clob=resultSet.getClob(1);

String outString= clob.getSubString(1l, (int)clob.length());
return outString;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get al characters printed ok you have to ensure that the encoding in MySQL, jsp file and resulting html are the same. If your choosen encoding is UTF-8 then the MySQL table must be in UTF-8, the jsp file should have being written with UTF-8, and in the html that goes to the browser there must be a tag like:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: My MySQL database is using UTF-8 encoding, and my HTML/JSP is in UTF-8 by using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />`  and  `<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>`, unfortunately no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this directive to JSP page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```